# Putting meta tag in a div to simulate mobile phone

Tags: html, meta

I'm trying to create a div in the bottom of my page to display an Iphone and simulate my page as if it was in mobile.

```
<div>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=350, initial-scale=1">
  <div id="iphone6">
    <div id="iphone6-screen">
      <header></header>
      <main></main>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I believe adding a meta tag in the div somehow would work but to no avail.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that.

`<meta viewport>` is only allowed in the `<head>` and is only supported by devices with small displays (since it is designed to be used to tell a device that the webpage hasn't been designed without taking small displays into consideration).

---

If you want to control the size of the div, then use `height`, and `width` in CSS.

Comment: I have the height and width set to the dimensions of the phone but the content inside doesn't look like it is being displayed on a phone. Looks like it would on a desktop with the width of 350px

Comment: Well, it is still in a much larger *page* so media queries wouldn't match smaller sizes. You might be able to hack something with an iframe. Honestly though, if you want to simulate a phone display, then use the developer tools in a desktop browser and don't try to build a website to do it.